# Labelling radio and checkbox elements

Tags: html, xhtml, semantics

What's the most appropriate, semantically correct way to label checkbox and radio elements? Obviously, giving each one a unique `id` attribute is an option and using that in id a `<label for="">`, but this seems like it would break the semantic grouping. Putting unenclosed text next to the `input` element just seems...wrong.

Edit:
Additionally, how should one denote the label for a group of such elements? (i.e. not the description of each option, but the description of the whole group)

Answer (score 3):

Using `<label for="">` is the correct way to do that. The grouping of radio buttons is done by denoting the group via the name attribute and individual elements via the id attribute. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg1"><label for="rbg1">Button One</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg2"><label for="rbg2">Button Two</label><br>
<input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg3"><label for="rbg3">Button Three</label><br>
```

As for putting a label over the entire group, just put them in a container that has a text container above the stack of buttons (or checkboxes). Example:

```
<div>
  <h3>My Radio Button Group</h3>
  <input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg1"><label for="rbg1">Button One</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg2"><label for="rbg2">Button Two</label><br>
  <input type="radio" name="rbg" id="rbg3"><label for="rbg3">Button Three</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Would a fieldset + legend not be more 'correct' than a div and h3?

Comment: Adding a fieldset/legend would work, but a heading is also acceptable in my opinion. Something to keep in mind with <legend> is that common screen readers will read the legend text before each label inside the fieldset, so the above would result in the output: "My Radio Button Group Button One, My Radio Button Group Button Two, My Radio Button Group Button Three". As you can imagine, that gets quite repetitive!  I also prefer to use <p> or lists or <div> rather than <br> for separating form controls.

Comment: @dotjay: Yes, of course. This is a simplified demonstration, not a finished product.

Answer (score 1):

I mostly use Chris Coyiers HTML ipsum : http://html-ipsum.com/

always a good helper